# Ordering the JSON data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking way to order data wich is coming from my JSON Provider:

```
[{"Username":"Mehmet","UserID":2,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":1},
{"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":2},
{"Username":"Erçin","UserID":1,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":3},
{"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":4},
{"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":5},
{"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":6},
{"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":7},
{"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":8},
{"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":9}]
```

There is two more important thing for ordering:

1. OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber
2. By UserID First; let me explain:

I want to order them firstly by OkeyTableChairNumber; this is done by Server Side already. Data coming ordered by OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber ASC...

Now the bull,
I would like to order them by UserID but; for example if I took  UserID == 1 it should order them like: UserID == 1 field, will be come to first field. and upper objects will removed and added to end of the list...

For view:

**UserID == 1**

```
 [{"Username":"Erçin","UserID":1,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":3},
 {"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":4},
 {"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":5},
 {"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":6},
 {"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":7},
 {"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":8},
 {"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":9},
 {"Username":"Mehmet","UserID":2,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":1},
 {"Username":null,"UserID":0,"OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber":2}]
```

**C# Solution I made before; But I need JS solutions:**

```
int yourSitPositionIndex = playersOnTheTableWithEmpytPositions.ToList().FindIndex(x => x.UserID == userID);
var beforePlayers = playersOnTheTableWithEmpytPositions.ToList().GetRange(0, yourSitPositionIndex);
IEnumerable<tbl_Okey_TablePlayer> afterPlayers = playersOnTheTableWithEmpytPositions.Except(beforePlayers);
IEnumerable<tbl_Okey_TablePlayer> newPositions = afterPlayers.Concat(beforePlayers);
```

Comment: Why down vote, just explain.

Comment: (don't know about the downvotes) What have you tried? Is you data into a string or into a javascript object?

Comment: Thank you; my data came by jQuery.parseJSON(obj) (edit: btw I tried JSON.search but i'm newbie on json)

Comment: In your example, do you really need to have the elements with `OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber=1` and `OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber=2` at the very end, or having them anywhere after the `UserID=1` element will be fine too? (And again, what have you tried?)

Comment: @Valune thank you for helping; I really need elements with OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber; imagine them like database row.

Comment: @undefined, it is not just an order. Your duplicate flag in the wrong place...

Comment: I added to question c# solution for logic...

Comment: Not a duplicate, you can't solve this problem with a simple sort, since the initial state of the array has to be considered.

Comment: I'll reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion of your C# solution:

```
var wantedId = 1;

var index = 0, result;
//int yourSitPositionIndex = playersOnTheTableWithEmpytPositions.ToList().FindIndex(x => x.UserID == userID);
while (index < data.length && data[index].UserID != wantedId) index += 1;
if (index < data.length) {
    //var beforePlayers = playersOnTheTableWithEmpytPositions.ToList().GetRange(0, yourSitPositionIndex);
    var beforePlayers = data.slice(0, index);
    //IEnumerable<tbl_Okey_TablePlayer> afterPlayers = playersOnTheTableWithEmpytPositions.Except(beforePlayers);
    var afterPlayers = data.slice(index);
    //IEnumerable<tbl_Okey_TablePlayer> newPositions = afterPlayers.Concat(beforePlayers);
    result = afterPlayers.concat(beforePlayers);
} else {
    result = data;
}
```

- There is no `FindIndex` in the core of javascript, so I did a while loop to find the index
- I use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to replace `GetRange`
- Rest of the code should be clear enough. The all code could be simplified with libraries like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqp1hxfL/)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to order by UserID DESC, OkeyTable... ASC

You can define a customer sort function:

In action: http://repl.it/XZm

```
var json = [/*all your data */]
function idSort(a,b){
    if(a["UserID"] !== b["UserID"]){
        return b["UserID"] - a["UserID"];
    } else {
        return a["OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber"] - b["OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber"];
    }
}
var sorted = json.sort(idSort);
```

Results:

```
[ { Username: 'Mehmet', UserID: 2, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 1 },
  { Username: 'Erçin', UserID: 1, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 3 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 2 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 4 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 5 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 6 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 7 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 8 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 9 } ]
```

Here is UserID ASC, OkeyTable...ASC:

```
function idSort(a,b){
    var notZero = (a["UserID"] > 0 && b["UserID"] > 0);
    var notEqual = (a["UserID"] !== b["UserID"]);
    if(notZero && notEqual){
        return a["UserID"] - b["UserID"];
    } else {
        return a["OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber"] - b["OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber"];
    }
}
var sorted = json.sort(idSort);
```

Results:

```
[ { Username: 'Erçin', UserID: 1, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 3 },
  { Username: 'Mehmet', UserID: 2, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 1 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 2 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 4 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 5 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 6 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 7 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 8 },
  { Username: null, UserID: 0, OkeyTablePlayerChairNumber: 9 } ]
```

In action: http://repl.it/XZm/1